# Should "slaughter" be a synonym of "dhabihah"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There are 7 questions tagged [slaughter](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slaughter), all of which are about ritual slaughter of animals, which has the tag [dhabihah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dhabihah) (10 questions).

Should these be made synonyms?

Comment: Yes slaughter and dhabihah is the same thing

Comment: I see no reason why not. Merged and synonymed.